# No provider for w

Tags: angular, angular-dependency-injection

How can I identify which service is not provided.

I run **ng serve** to serve angular project.
it is optimized and instead of service name in error message I have "w" or some other words
I set providedIn property of @Injectable to 'root'
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root',
})